# How to understand this regular expression?

Tags: regex

May someone please put some light on this regex...It looks so difficult to understand...

```
/^[0-9]{1,}((\.){1}[0-9]{1,}){0,1}$/.test(value)
```

Value is what I send from the text box to validate...

Comment: You first have to learn about it in order to understand it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: You can use an online explainer.  In your case: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%28%28%5C.%29%7B1%7D%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%29%7B0%2C1%7D%24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^           // start with
[0-9]{1,}   // one or more of 0-9
(
  (\.){1}   // a period
  [0-9]{1,} // one or more of 0-9 
){0,1}      // zero or one of this group
$           // until end
```

Or even shorter:

```
^[0-9]+((\.)[0-9]+)?$
```

i.e. a series of digits optionally followed by a period character and a series of digits.

So anything like

```
0011221100
12345
1.23456
0.0
0000.1111
```

will match.

Comment: Careful FYI the dot is backslashed meaning it is a real period.

Comment: or _even_ shorter: `^\d+(\.\d+)?$`

Comment: @Howard, err, why would you need the capture group around the `.`? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Bart I don't want to, but the original regex does. So I didn't want to change that.

Comment: Ah, I see. @PremanshuMishra, you can safely remove the capturing group 2 (the one around the `.`): it stores no significant information. The only thing it could possibly store is the index of the `'.'` in your match, but that would be the same as the start-index of group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Edit : The op was different so I update the explanation.

**To put it simply :**

```
    "
^           # Assert position at the beginning of the string
[0-9]       # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   {1,}        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   (           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      \.          # Match the character “.” literally
   ){1}        # Exactly 1 times
   [0-9]       # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
      {1,}        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
){0,1}      # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\$           # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

Edit 2:

You *might* want to write this regex like this :

```
^\d+((\.)+\d+)?$
```

It has **EXACTLY** the same meaning as the original one and it is of course more readable and compact.

Edit 3:

To account for an optional integer part before the . simply change your quantifier from {1,} to {0,} i.e. from + to * :

```
^\d*((\.)+\d+)?$
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply...This regex is not accepting numbers if they begin with .(decimal) How that may be amended...I m new to the world of regex...